# vlookup to leave cells empty if value is 0

Tags: vba, excel, formula, vlookup

I have written this code so far but is says that there is an application or object error..

```
.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),"""")=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),""""))"
```

I have used this code so far successfully but I changed as you can see and it wont run now.

```
.Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(I2/VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),"""")=0,"""",IFERROR(I2/VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),""""))"
```

The entire part as it is right now after the edits,

```
With Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0))"
.Value = .Value
End With
```

[image]

Comment: @danieltakeshi I was the one that asked the others and I assure you that if you look closer they are not duplicates

Comment: this one has no division or multiplication... its simple a vlookup..

Comment: try them both and see yourself if you can solve them with same code.

Comment: `A2&""B2""` means `A2&"B2"`. Is that what you are looking for . If not then remove, quotes.

Comment: yes, if you put manually the formula in excel you must replace ""B2"" with "B2". But for VBA, it only works like this A2&""B2""

Comment: What cyboashu meant was that, are you trying to reference B2 as a Text (String) or a cell reference, if a cell reference, then remove the quotes `A2&B2`

Comment: A sorry for that.. yes as a text...

Comment: `.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0))"` works for me.

Comment: unfortunatelly, I cannot figure out why it keeps appearing like in the picture I uploaded..

Comment: The N/A error means the value is not found - this is not catered for in your formula. You could wrap it all in an IFERROR to avoid that.

Comment: a ok !! how can I alter it with IFERROR?

Comment: I went with ISERROR in the end because it's easier in this situation, but I think this should do what you want `.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)),"""",IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)))"`

Comment: Finally it worked!! thanks a lot buddy for your patience!!